# master the U.S. SAT English vocabulary book VS master U.S. SAT English vocabulary book

Tags: articles, definite-article

> I mastered the U.S. SAT English vocabulary book in less than two months.

> I mastered U.S. SAT English vocabulary book in less than two months.

> I mastered a U.S. SAT English vocabulary book in less than two months.

Do we need the article 'the' or 'a'?

'SAT English vocabulary book' is just an ordinary book which I can buy at a bookstore.

Comment: _The_, because it refers to a particular publication relating to the American SAT test.

Answer (score 1):

You would use "a" or "the".

Probably "the" because I guess there is one particular publication that is *the* US SAT vocabulary book. Or the listener knows which book you mean

On the other hand, if this is actually a type of publication, and there are many different books that are all US SAT vocabulary books, it could be "a".
Moreover, if you are not talking about a particular title, you'd be more likely to say "I mastered the vocabulary" and not "I mastered a vocabulary book".  Since you are not learning the book, you are learning the words.